# How to copy worksheets with renaming as per list?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying the below code, to copy a 'master' worksheet with renaming as per values in worksheet 'List', which is working only once.

If I try to run the macro again renaming does not happen.

> runtime Error '1004':
>   name is already taken . try a different one

The macro should work one loop and end. When rerun the macro should jump to the next value in the 'List'.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Master")
Set sh = Sheets("List")
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False
    Sheets("Master").Copy After:=sh
    Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
    ActiveSheet.Name = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("F3").Value = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
Exit For
Next i
ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing some info to tell the VBA code to loop if the current name (`sh.Range("A" & i).value`) was already taken by a worksheet.

Following is what I have come up with:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Dim tmpWS As Worksheet 'will be used to test whether a worksheet already exists

    Set ws = Sheets("Master")
    Set sh = Sheets("List")

    'storing the last row I think is better as well as using explicit
    'definition of the range (sh.Range rather then Range alone)
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 To lastRow

        'trying to set a worksheet variable with the new name from the list
        'if the result returns a set variable (variable not returning "Nothing")
        'it means the worksheet exists
        On Error Resume Next '--> will continue even if it encounters an error.  Don't overuse this
        Set tmpWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sh.Range("a" & i).Value2)
        On Error GoTo 0 '--> will set back default error handling.  From now on, the "Resume Next" is disabled.

        'this is true if worksheet named "sh.Range("A" & i).Value" does not exist
        If (tmpWS Is Nothing) Then

            Excel.Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False
            Sheets("Master").Copy After:=sh
            ActiveSheet.Name = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
            ActiveSheet.Range("F3").Value = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
            Excel.Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
            Exit For

        Else

            'force tmpWS to be set to nothing prior making another run in the loop
            Set tmpWS = Nothing

        End If
    Next i

    ws.Activate

    'important to reactivate the screen updating at the end
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Useful reference
**[On Error Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement)**

Comment: thank you its working just fine. To add to this how can we protect few cells in the copy which is created?

Comment: I'm glad it worked out well, thanks for the feedback.  Now you can accept this answer if it's suiting you.  For the additional question in your comment, you should create a new thread on the site if you can't find anything to apply to your particular needs.  This way, it will be easier for other users to find question / answer to their problems.  If you want to try it yourself, you could record a macro while protecting/unprotecting a worksheet. Also see [Worksheet.Protect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect)